# Autowiring a subclass but using parent class as reference

Tags: java, spring

Say I have the below class hierarchy:

```java
// Not a component
public class Parent {
}

// See update; this resides in another application context
@Component
public class Child extends Parent {
}
```

I would like to autowire the `Child` bean using constructor injection.

```java
@Component
public class Test {

    private final Parent parent;

    public Test(@Qualifier("child") Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

But Spring is not letting me do this and I get an exception thrown saying:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.foo.Parent' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=child)}`

Is there a way to make this work?

### Update

OK, first of all, there is no way you could have come up with an answer to this problem as I made a mistake and did not analyse the situation properly before asking the question.

So what was happening was that the "child" in my case resided in a different application context, which happened to be a bean in the main application context. Because of this reason, what would have been a standard Spring practice, would not have worked for me.

I will post my answer as the solution to this updated scenario.

Comment: I would say that this works normally. However, I do not use the component scanning via `@Component` then. How about when you remove the `@Qualifier`?

Comment: what's the gain you going to get by not adding @component to parent? behind the scene spring expects all the depend beans to be ready to run. since child extends parent it must needs to be annotated to assert spring to create Parent bean, either annotate or do not annotate any

Comment: @ParthibanManickam I'm thinking the same too. Trying by annotating the parent with `@Component`

Comment: I would not say that annotating Parent AND Child is a good solution. I would expect that when everything works as expected that then TWO beans are present, leading to appropriate error.

Comment: **Unable to reproduce** using Spring 5.1.3. Added your code as-is to a Spring project I have, with a print statement in the `Test` constructor, and it printed without error. Are you sure your `Child` class is picked up by the component scanning?

Comment: What above comment says. But you could try giving component an explicit name: `@Component("child")`, so it's definitely qualified the way you want.

Comment: I would also expect the component scan NOT to pick the child for some reason. Setting-up logging for spring to DEBUG lets spring logs all the beans it creates.

Comment: Btw, this situation is exactly the reason why I do not use classpath scan - one never knows what is (or is not) on the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution involved simply looking up the bean from the other application context as follows:

```java
@Component
public class Test {

    private final Parent parent;

    public Test(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.parent = applicationContext.getBean("anotherContext", ApplicationContext.class).getBean("child", Parent.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you kinda imitate situation when you try to autowire some class from any outer library. You have to get beans through xml or java config. I think this should work and you should to remove component from Child.

But anyway there should be big reasons to do that. Simple spring autorwiring is more concise and traditional

```
package com.bssys.ufap.report.springconfig;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
  @Bean
  public Parent getChild() {
    return new Child();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know this, but in my case Child is already a bean and I don't want to change that.